# How to setup the javacc in linux system

Tags: java, installation, javacc

how to install **javacc2.0** (in opt/tools/java) in **linux system**?

If i do yum install javacc, then it install 5 version.

Please help me out.

Comment: Versions back to 3.1 are available at https://java.net/projects/javacc/downloads/directory/oldversions. Changes to JavaCC rarely alter its behaviour (substantively) on existing files.  If you have a file that was compiled with 2.0, I'd expect it would compile with version 3.1 without any noticeable change in the behaviour of the generated code.

Comment: Hi, its working, the one which i downloaded didnt have most of the files, like javacc script file. Now i downloaded the right one. Thanks a lot.